# Load myApp into Jailbroken iPod Touch 4G

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, ipod-touch, jailbreak

I have developed a simple camera based app in Xcode. Since I can't run this app in iOS simulator. I would like to transfer this app to my JailBroken iPod touch 4G.

I don't have iPhone developer Licence or certificate. I have not so far registered with them. How can I get this done? Is it an absolute must to register with Apple, get my "Provisioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install OpenSSH from Cydia, then open Terminal and type this:

```
scp /path/to/application.app root@<ip address of ipod>:/Applications/
```

then hit enter. It should ask for a password which is `alpine`.